# Performing 'text to columns' on a number of columns - loop required

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have some code that I use to perform text to columns and it has worked fine for me for on one column.

Unfortunately, I have up to 60 columns that I need to split to columns (in sheet 3). I would like to copy column a in sheet 3 to column a in sheet 4 and perform text to columns on it. Then I would like to copy Column B in Sheet 3 to the next available row in sheet 4 (after the delimited text), and repeat the process.

When I start my macro below, it appears to be looping through sheet 3 but after running it there is nothing in sheet 4.

```
Sub LoopColumns()


Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 60
'Check to see if column is blank
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Columns(i)) <> 1048576 Then
Columns(i).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Select

For j = 1 To 10000
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Columns(j)) <> 1048576 Then
Columns(j).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns(j).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End If
Next j

End If
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Next i

End Sub
```

I think that my logic is ok. Can you see where I am going wrong exactly? Thanks!

Comment: i'd try to more explicit when specifying objects so for example change `Columns(j).Select` to `sheets("Sheet4").Columns(j).Select` etc as I suspect it is referencing the wrong sheet somewhere within the code

Comment: @ whytheq (nice name by the way) I replaced both the column(i).select and column(j).select but nothing seemed to change. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ok - I'll attempt to reproduce your procedure. Have you stepped through the code one line at a time?

Comment: is sheet4 initially blank?...if so why do you do `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Columns(j)) <> 1048576`

Comment: ok - I've posted a solution which works on my pc; I'll probably change your bit of code `<> 1048576` as this is not a very good idea....especially if someone uses a different version of XL !

Comment: Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1") pastes everything to "A1"

Comment: @JüriRuut - no it doesn't; just tested and it pastes the whole column; have you tested?

Comment: Yes, I tested to some extent. You overwrite 10 000 times A1.

Comment: @JüriRuut - have you tested the OP code ...or my solution code?

Comment: @JüriRuut please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213590(v=office.11).aspx) for documentation about A1. It says `Destination   Optional Variant. A Range object that specifies where Microsoft Excel will place the results. If the range is larger than a single cell, the top left cell is used.`....top left cell is used

Comment: Yes, it pastes the whole column. But as you use a static address, all the columns you paste to column j, will be columnized from column A. Actually, whytheq already fixed it in his code ( Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, x))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something simpler like this should do it:

```
Sub LoopColumns()


Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

For i = 1 To 60

    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Excel.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(i)) <> 1048576 Then

        Excel.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(i).Copy

        x = Excel.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft)(1, 2).Column

        If x = 2 Then
        x = 1
        Else: x = x
        End If

        Excel.Sheets("Sheet4").Select
        Excel.Sheets("Sheet4").Columns(x).EntireColumn.Select
        Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste

        Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, x), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
                Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    End If



Next i

Excel.Sheets("Sheet3").Select

End Sub
```

**EDIT** to take out the slightly bizarre `IF` statement in the above

```
Sub LoopColumns()


Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

For i = 1 To 60

    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Excel.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(i)) <> 1048576 Then

        Excel.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(i).Copy

        x = Excel.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column

        Excel.Sheets("Sheet4").Select

        If Cells(1, x) <> "" Then x = x + 1


            Excel.Sheets("Sheet4").Columns(x).EntireColumn.Select
            Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste

            Excel.Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, x), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
                    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
                    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    End If



Next i

Excel.Sheets("Sheet3").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ whytheq....I ran your code but it seems like it just keeps replacing prexisting text. It looks like all the columns are being pasted into column A in sheet 4 instead of the next available empty column.

Comment: -1 The problem with this code is that `Excel.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft)(1, 2).Column` will return 2 if the first column is blank or not. This leads to you repeatedly overwriting the first column if no data (or only the first column) is in the destination sheet. Rather than checking `if x = 2`, you should check if the first cell in the column is blank. I.E. `if Cells(1,x) = ""`.If not, then x should be 1 larger.

Comment: @user1771483 - I'll add a second version with the Edit suggested by Daniel.

Comment: @DanielCook - I've changed the code using your suggestion ; although I cannot replicate the bug that you describe. Just so we are singing from the same hymn book; I have several columns of data in Sheet3 and Sheet4 is blank before running the procedure

Comment: @ Whytheq yes sorry there will be several columns in sheet 3 and sheet 4 will be blank when the procedure starts

Comment: @user1771483 - think we got there in the end!

Comment: @Whytheq I was being a bit of an idiot. Row 1 in sheet 3 was empty which would of course meant that cell(1,x) was empty. So it appears to be working now. One glitch though. When I run the code it keeps throwing up a msgbox asking "Do you want to replace the contents of the destination cells". I have to click yes for it to continue. One column in sheet 4 is then left blank before another column is pasted in. Strangely this only began maybe 10 columns into sheet 3

Comment: let me try to replicate - I have only been testing on 6 columns; please can you test the vba on a new workbook of data just in case it is something to do with the workbook you are using

Comment: @ Daniel Cook - sorry just saw your edit. Thanks. Unfortuantely that also throws up msgboxes as I explained in last comment.

Comment: @user1771483 it works fine on my machine - please create a new workbook with just two sheets "Sheet3" and "Sheet4" and then paste in say 25 columns of test data and then run the code - I suspect it will work fine. There is probably some small amounts of data in the original workbook that is causing this funny.

Comment: you could add in "Excel.Application.Displayalerts = False" to stop the alerts but these alerts are telling you that some data somewhere in the sheet is being over-written so best to let Excel deliver these messages as it indicates something is wrong.

Comment: @Whytheq I still have the same problem but I think you are probably right - it's probably something to do with the original data. Intermittent blank columns aren't a problem anyway, I have code for that but do you know how to automatically close these msgboxes?

Comment: @whytheq Wow I'm way to slow. Thanks a million for everything. Accepting your answer now.